# How can I set up a FK relationship using EF5 Code First API so as to not allow deletion of the parent if rows exist in the child?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

I have the following tables that exist in my database. I am trying to set the foreign key
but I am not sure I am doing this correctly. What I have is a relationship between the
table [Application] and the table [TestAccount] where there are for example three different
[Application] rows and each will have zero or many [TestAccount] rows. I do not want to be
able to delete an [Application] row if there is already an existing [TestAccount] row.

Here's my SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application] (
    [ApplicationId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [DataVersion] ROWVERSION,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Application] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicationId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestAccount] (
    [TestAccountId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId] INT,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [DataVersion] ROWVERSION,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TestAccount] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestAccountId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT fk_AccountApplication FOREIGN KEY (ApplicationId) REFERENCES Application(ApplicationId)
);
```

I am trying to configure this for EF and here's what I have so far:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Application>()
      HasKey(a => a.ApplicationId);
      Property(a => a.ApplicationId).
      HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).
      IsRequired();

  modelBuilder.Entity<Application>().
      Property(a => a.Name).
      IsRequired().
      HasMaxLength(50);

  modelBuilder.Entity<TestAccount>()
      HasKey(a => a.TestAccountId);
      Property(a => a.TestAccountId).
      HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).
      IsRequired();

  modelBuilder.Entity<TestAccount>().
      Property(t => t.Name).
      IsRequired();
```

Can someone tell me if I am going about this correctly with the foreign keys in the database and also
show me how I can configure the foreign key using the fluent API.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model looks something like this:

```
public class Application 
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestAccount> TestAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class TestAccount
{
    public int TestAccountId { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping of your FK to your navigation property via fluent would be like this:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Application>()
        .HasMany(a => a.TestAccounts)
        .WithRequired(t => t.Application)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Thanks. What would happen if I try to delete an Application row and there were TestAccounts that depended on it. Would the FK in the database stop that from happening or would EF be the one to stop it first?

Comment: I updated my answer - I left out the cascade delete false, you will need the fluent mapping. You'll get an error from System.Entity (EF) saying you can't delete the relationship.

Comment: thanks again. One more quick question. Does this allow there to be zero TestAccounts for the application. Do I need to have a .HasOptional(xxxxx) ?

Comment: This is a 1 to 0..many relationship - a Test account **must** have an application (required), but an application can have 0 to infinite number of test accounts.